# Symfony Custom Form Select Value

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony3 and I want to be able to display custom select values by combining two fields together such as name and city. So, in essence in the select box it would show this:

```
 ------------------------------------
 John Smith - Denver
 ------------------------------------
 Abe Lincoln - Washington D.C
 ------------------------------------
 George Washington - Washington D.C
 ------------------------------------
 etc...
 ------------------------------------
```

Here's my form...

```
$builder->add('person', EntityType::class, array(
            'required'=>false,
            'class'=>'AppBundle:Person',
            'choice_label'=>'name',
            'label'=>'Choose the person',
            'empty_data'=>null,
            'placeholder'=>"None",
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) {
                return $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
            }
        ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Symfony Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label) says `choice_label` can be also a callable which gives you two options.

1. Create a getter for composed value that should represent entity like:

   ```
   class Person {
       // ...

       public function getComposedName() {
           return $this->name . ' - ' . $this->city;
       }

   }
   ```

And then in the form set `choice_label` to `'composedName'`. 
Please note that it's `composedName`, and not `getComposedName`, because Symfony will use [`PropertyAccesor`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html) here, it will try also getting value with a getter `getComposedName`.

This may be useful if you'll need this value in other places

2. If you need this only in this particular form, then you can pass an anonymous function directly to the form:

   ```
   'choice_label'=> function($person) {
       return $person->getName(). ' - ' . $person->getCity();
   }
   ```